# Embedding Verdana in a dynamic text field, need to make it bold - do I have to buy Verdana Bold?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, bold

First off, I don't have a copy of Verdana bold.  It's no where on my hd and I don't know the first thing about making fonts so that is out of the question.

I've been searching for a couple of hours now and it seems the tried and true solution is to embed multiple versions of the font off the stage.

Ridiculous.  Right?  In either case, I am pleading to all you Flash Jedi out there to please tell me there is another way?  I refuse to turn to the dark side.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have to buy it. Second, this is how it's done in Flex so it  can give you some insight.

```
@font-face{
src:url('fonts/Verdana.ttf');
font-family:Verdana;/*any name you want actually, you can have it VerdanaBold*/
font-weight:bold;
}
```

To call it later from a component, let's say a Label

```
<s:Label text="Your text here" fontFamily="Verdana"/>
```

The long answer is that I can't believe you don't have Verdana on your system, how come? If you see it in Office software or even in notepad font settings but don't know how to get it, assuming it's a Windows system, look under Control Panel > Fonts.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with making labels or writing flex.

Comment: p.s. I do have Verdana on my system, but no where do I have a file called "Verdana BOLD"  so I assume the bold is done dynamically or is hidden.

Comment: I take that back, my coworker found a copy of Verdana bold in his Fonts folder, however, it doesn't show up in the list of fonts in Flash IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Flash IDE, embedding it outside the stage (anywhere - it just need to be on your project) is, indeed, the best way to do it. Basically, if you have a TextField with font embedding set, Flash only embeds the basic font, ignoring the rest - so if you want text with <b> somewhere in there, the bold font has to be embedded.

You probably do have Verdana bold in your system, maybe you just can't see it (depends on your system). Just try creating a Verdana TextField and enabling bold.

You can also have it added to the library as a font asset, but it has problems of its own. Feature wise, the hidden textfield trick works best.

You can also embed fonts with the [embed] meta tag, but that's a bigger can of worms for you if you're working with the IDE (since it means to start using the Flex SDK from it).

Comment: So I made a second textfield outside the main stage with Verdana set to Bold.  I recompiled and made sure everything was set to bold on the main one... but it had no effect..  Do you happen to know if deleting all textfields with the font, then remaking them would help?  I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: Hey Zeh.  I'm to the point where I don't believe I can do this any other way but with Flex...  Can you tell me if I need to buy anything more than what I already have to do this?  I have Adobe Web Premium CS3 with Flash IDE...  Are the rest of the tools free downloads?  I'm on Flex in a Week, but it is all so overwhelming...  I'd like to know before I delve into it!

Comment: You don't have to buy anything - if you have any Flash IDE it's fine. You can create a TextField with your font, another (hidden) textfield with the bold font, and when you, say, set the .htmlText of the original TextField with a <b> tag somewhere in there, it's supposed to work. Unless you deleted Verdana Bold from your system by accident, you should have it installed; if not, or if you're on a non-Windows system, you can download it (legally) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/corefonts/files/the%20fonts/final/verdan32.exe/download

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the library panel and from the top right corner (click the little triangle and grid looking thingy) and choose "New Font". There you can embed bold Verdana and use it in your code.

Comment: So, I did that and it still did not work...  Do you want to take a look at the source files?

Comment: Sorry, I've been away. Yes, you can send me the file and I can take a look.